# how to find all the labels for a given file in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I know one awkward  solution for this taks will be :

- first use `ct ls` to get the entire version info of the file
- and pipe the version info to a parsing script to actually get the labels of the file .

But I guess ClearCase should have a "build in" solution for this task without support from any external scripts.

Please help me if you happen to know a "build in" solution for the task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Haiyuan: just completed my answer to list *all* labels of a file. No "build in" solution I am afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[`fmt_ccase`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)** contains all the format-string for various ClearCase elements.

For a version of a file, you can:

```
 cleartool descr -fmt "%l\n" /path/to/a/version
```

> `%l`
>   **Labels**: For versions, all attached labels; the null string otherwise.
>   **Labels are output as a comma-separated list, enclosed in parentheses**.
>   A `<SPACE>` character follows each comma.
>
> **Variants**:
>
> - `%Cl`
>     **Max labels**: Specify the maximum number of labels to display with the max-field-width parameter (see [Specifying field width](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)).
>     If there are more labels, "`...`" is appended to the output.
>     If no max-field-width is specified, the maximum default value is 3.
> - `%Nl`
>     No commas: Suppress the parentheses and commas in label list output;
>     **separate labels with spaces only**.

So the result can be:

```
Labels: (Rel3.1C, Rel3.1D, Rel3.1E)
Labels without commas or parens: Rel3.1C Rel3.1D Rel3.1E
```

In both case, you still need to parse the result, but at least the output can contain *only* the labels, as in:

```
Rel3.1C Rel3.1D Rel3.1E
```

---

[onaclov2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241852/onaclov2000) adds (from the comments):

> The only problem with this is that you are grabbing the label on the specific version of the file.
>   Given that branches etc can exist, we'll need to be able to get ALL labels on a file.
>   If you use version tree graphical and select tools -> "locate" you can see *ALL* the labels attached to that file.
>   Is there a common command in cleartool that will return the results of "locate", or "contents"?

The `lsvtree` (graphical version tree) does display the labels of all the versions of the element currently seen by the view when you click "Label Name"

That being said, there does not seem to be a "built-in" solution and some parsing is involved:

For instance (which is a bit shorter than the OP version but still based on a `cleartool ls`):

```
ct ls -l addon.xml@@|grep version|gawk "{gsub(/^version.*@@\\\\/,\"\",$0) ; gsub(/ \ [.*/,\"\",$0); print $0}"
```

(GnuWin32 syntax)

or, only with a dynamic view:

```
cd m:/myView/path/to/addon.xml@@
# list all files, not directories: the files are the labels
dir /B /A-D
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that you are grabbing the label on the specific version of the file, given that branches etc can exist, we'll need to be able to get ALL labels on a file, if you use version tree graphical and select tools -> "locate" you can see ALL the labels attached to that file, is there a common command in cleartool that will return the results of "locate", or "contents"?

Comment: @onaclov2000: not sure about the downvote, but I have extended my answer to address the "list all labels" query.

Comment: I upvoted you due to your update! sorry it didn't come sooner, I happened upon this question again during a google search

Comment: I know this is an old post but when I try the `ct ls -l.....` I get an `unterminated regexp` at the last gsub right after `\` at the space

Comment: that should be `\\`

Comment: @VonC I don't have a working example of what he was trying to do

Comment: @depperm But you have a working example of what *you* are trying to do: please edit the answer to illustrate what is working for your case.

Comment: @VonC no i don't...I'm using the `ct ls -l....` line and it isn't working

Comment: @depperm OK. On which OS? With which shell? (Windows CMD, Linux bash?) And which version of ClearCase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178097/discussion-between-depperm-and-vonc).

Answer (score 3):

The IBM article "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" is a great source for find query.
To expand on the "**`lsvtree`**" bit mentioned by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322824/how-to-find-all-the-labels-for-a-given-file-in-clearcase/2323757#2323757), you have:

> **To find all elements with any label**:
>
> Windows:

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec "cleartool lsvtree -a %CLEARCASE_PN%" | findstr
"("
./hello.c@@/main/1 (LABEL100, LABEL99, LABEL98, LABEL97)
./foo.xml@@/main/BR1/1 (REL2)
./bar.o@@/main/1 (REL1)
```

> UNIX/Linux:

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec 'cleartool lsvtree -a $CLEARCASE_PN' | grep "("

./hello.c@@/main/1 (LABEL100, LABEL99, LABEL98, LABEL97)
./foo.xml@@/main/BR1/1 (REL2)
./bar.o@@/main/1 (REL1)
```

That finds only labels for versions currently selected in the view, but you could reuse the `lsvtree` part to grep all versions of a file with labels.

Comment: I took the liberty to expand on your initial link. StackOverflow is a Q&A site which aims at including as much information as possible in each answer, in order to limit its dependency to external sources (like this link which could expire/be changed at any time). +1 btw.