# Command to find labels applied on particular branch

Tags: clearcase

Command to find labels applied on particular branch..

Suppose i have a branch name called BR_test , i want to know what are all the labels applied on this branch.

Answer (score 2):

If this was UCM, a simple `lsbl` would be enough:

```
 cleartool lsbl -stream myStream@\mypvob
```

But if this is base ClearCase, the simple way would be to determine what element (directory or file) is *always* labeled (typically a root directory), and fetch all the [labels on that element for a given branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322824/how-to-find-all-the-labels-for-a-given-file-in-clearcase), through a combination of [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) and `cleartool describe`, based on [`fmt_ccase` format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) (Windows syntax here):

```
 C:\mySnapshotView\myVob\myRootDir>
 ct find . -nrec -name "." -ver "brtype(myBranch)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt "%l" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

That will list all labels for all versions of that element for a specific branch.

Comment: Thanks a lott Von, appreciate your fast response