# Which tag or branch is created from a particular branch

Tags: clearcase

In ClearCase suppose I have a branch App_Feb_Branch. Now I want to know if any Tag or Label has been created from this branch. How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can list baselines (for ClearCase UCM) or grep for version with a label (for base ClearCase).

See "[Command to find labels applied on particular branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080447/6309)":

```
ct find . -nrec -name "." -ver "brtype(myBranch)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt "%l" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

With [fmt_ccase formatting options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), you can use the %l to only display labels for the versions found.

That is what the `cleartool descr -fmt "%l" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"` part of the `cleartool find` above does.