# Cleartool commands shows error

Tags: clearcase

```
FOR /F %%K IN('cleartool ls -recurse -short -nxn ') DO ( cleartool describe %%K | Find "labels:") > temp.txt
```

It gives an error

> Syntax of command is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find files with a specific label, it is easier to use the cleartool find command, as in "[ClearCase list of files with given label type applied](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitolite/$20branch$20deletion/gitolite/nytDWM5AbUw/EI90H4Upe48J)"

```
cleartool find . –version "lbtype(MY_LABEL-1.0)"
```

The Report Builder (also known in ClearCase Explorer as Report Wizard) can also allow you can navigate to `Elements/Labels`, which has the "Elements with Labels" and "Versions with Labels" reports.

---

More generally, your command would be better done in an `-exec` directive of a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?resultof=%22find%22%20) command:

```
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n %l\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

(as in "[how to find all the labels for a given file in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323757/6309)")