# Getting previous activity ids of a file in clearcase commandline

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I'm using windows. I need to extract activity ids of check ins in ClearCase.

I can get the current one through `cleartool describe` and then parsing the response for the word '`Activity`'.

**I'm looking to get the activity ids of it's previous versions**.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to parse the output of [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm), if you combine it with [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).

That allows you to:

- get the previous version of an existing version

  ```
   cd /path/to/view
   cleartool describe -fmt "%[version_predecessor]p" afile
  ```
- get all activity id with that version involved:

  ```
   cd /path/to/view
   cleartool describe -fmt "%[activity]p" afile@@/a/previous/version
  ```

(that is using the [**version-extended pathname `@@/...`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37944752/6309) returned by the first `cleartool describe`)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting an object selector required error for the first command. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @RamdasNair What do you type? What is your ClearCase version?

Comment: sorry, that was my bad. Accidentally messed up the syntax. Both seems to work just fine and makes sense instead of just parsing the entire describe output. :)

Comment: @RamdasNair Great! Can you add a comment with the exact syntax you used?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this one. Here it is: cleartool describe -fmt "%[version_predecessor]p afile

Didn't close the double quote. :/