# What does "branch@@branch@@branch" mean in Clearcase?

Tags: branch, clearcase

## Background

I am trying to axe away some elements that are no longer needed in clearcase.  I think I might have subverted some policy, becuase after I ran a `rmbranch` on the files I wanted to remove, each file ended up in this state:

```
/some/directory/@@/main/dev/retired_branch_time_stamp/oldViewNum1234/1/file.txt@@/main/dev/new_view_3425_nickname/1
```

I am familiar with `/some/directory/element@@/some/branch` but not with the double "@@" notation above.  Hench my question...

## Question

What does the `something@@something@@something` notation mean in clearcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Access labels of file through extended filename as directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37944752/6309)", everything after the `@@` is a [version-extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424471/6309) (see [`pathnames_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/pathnames_ccase.htm) )

- Branch: `element-pname@@branch-pname`
- Version: `element-pname@@version-selector`

So:

- The first part `/some/directory/@@/` is a VOB-extended namespace directory
- Then you have the pname followed by a version selector.

That does refer to the [concept of "extended namespace"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/cc_glossary.htm):

> An extension of the standard Windows or Linux or UNIX file system that allows access to versions of elements.